# Accessing IIS Hosted website from different machine using IP Address and Port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, web-hosting, user-permissions

I have hosted an ASP .NET MVC website on IIS 7 on a machine,
I have bounded the site with IP Address and Port and I can access it from that system by using http://[IP Address]:[Port Number], to get access from another system I have added  a rule in Windows firewall as mentioned in [this link](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html).

But after completing the process I am still getting "The site cant be reached" error,

I've tried different solution including giving Full control permissions to All Groups and user names as mentioned in following screenshot but still cant get access to website.

[image]

I've searched alot on internet but couldn't get any effective solution.

Comment: Run Binding Diagnostics, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and it should report more details.

Comment: Sounds like a connectivity issue rather than a file system issue if it works locally.  I'd reset your filesystems permissions, you should not allow the application full control.  Where/how is your server hosted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was an issue with my IP address which was dynamic, In beginning I  tried and assumed that I've configured the static IP successfully but unfortunately couldn't. Now we are going to buy a static IP for our Website.

Answer (score 1):

Few questions and suggestion that will help you in isolating the issue further.

1. Does the application come up fine when you browse to it over localhost and IP address directly on the server ?
2. Look into IIS logs and see if the requests are even reaching IIS and share the status code here. Default Location - C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc_websiteID
3. Stop your website in IIS. Create another website at port 80 and add a simple HelloWorld.html page and see if it comes up fine over localhost and also by accessing it from a client machine using IP address of the machine.
4. If step 3 works and the sample website works fine, then change the port of the sample website to the non-working one.
5. if step 4 fails, you need to concentrate in opening the port. You can also verify if the port is open or blocked by using a tool called PortQueryUI - Download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009)

Let me know if you have any follow up questions.